# delete item from observablecollection make the XML serialize update fail

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, observablecollection

I use an observable collection to save a list in my app, and use XML to save that list to isolated storage. the app is ok when i add item, but when i delete an item and restart app, it cant read the XML. I use i tools to get that XML from isolated storage and yes, its structure is wrong.

here is the code

```
public void saveToXML()
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();                       
            XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSetting = new XmlWriterSettings();
            xmlWriterSetting.Indent = true;
            using (storage)
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fsIdea = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Idea.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, storage))
                {
                    using (XmlWriter xWIdea = XmlWriter.Create(fsIdea, xmlWriterSetting))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer xSIdea = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<IdeaViewModel>));
                        xSIdea.Serialize(xWIdea, App.ViewModel.ItemsIdea);
                    }
                }                
            }
        }

        public void readFromXML()
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            if (!storage.FileExists("Idea.xml") )
            {
                saveToXML();
            }
            using (storage)
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fsIdea = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Idea.xml", FileMode.Open, storage))
                {
                    XmlSerializer xSIdea = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<IdeaViewModel>));
                    App.ViewModel.ItemsIdea = xSIdea.Deserialize(fsIdea) as ObservableCollection<IdeaViewModel>;
                }                
            }
        }
```

and here is the wrong XML file when i deleted item and restarted app, the error is at line 9, looks like the XML file still keep a part of the deleted item ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfIdeaViewModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <IdeaViewModel>
    <IdeaContent>sdfsd</IdeaContent>
  </IdeaViewModel>
  <IdeaViewModel>
    <IdeaContent>sdfds</IdeaContent>
  </IdeaViewModel>
</ArrayOfIdeaViewModel>aContent>sf</IdeaContent>
  </IdeaViewModel>
  <IdeaViewModel>
    <IdeaContent>sdfsd</IdeaContent>
  </IdeaViewModel>
  <IdeaViewModel>
    <IdeaContent>sdfds</IdeaContent>
  </IdeaViewModel>
</ArrayOfIdeaViewModel>
```

( i put the readFromXML() at constructor of app, the the saveToXML() at here

```
// Code to execute when the application is deactivated (sent to background)
    // This code will not execute when the application is closing
    private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        saveToXML();                     
    }

    // Code to execute when the application is closing (eg, user hit Back)
    // This code will not execute when the application is deactivated
    private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Ensure that required application state is persisted here.
        saveToXML();            
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save use [FileMode.Create instead of FileMode.OpenOrCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.filemode%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fsIdea = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Idea.xml", FileMode.Create, storage))
```

In your case you are just editting the old version of the file and thus you probably have some artifacts.

Comment: thank you so much :) the problem seem fixed, but im just wondering 2 more little question: 1. should i use above solution (only save in the terminate) or should i save the changed every time i modify the list in app, does the app has enough time for the save at last. 2. i've asked 3 or 4 question here and its seem you helped me quite immediately, thank you for that but :| do you stay online all the time ??? :)

Comment: @user3448806 As for 1 - it depends on your Data, how many times it is modified by the user, size of it and more. You have limited time when App is being Deactivated/Terminated. If it's not too much data and modifications I would save it just after the modification. Everything depends on the purpose of your App. As for 2 - Luckily not all the time ;)